# tabbed content-submit one id...don't touch the other

Tags: php, css, ajax

I'm doing some coding in php/mysql, using css.

Let's say I have a page with tabbed content, so that all the content is on the page but most is hidden until I click the relevant tab. When I do, that tab's content is shown and the others are hidden. No problem.

Now, say there are 2 tabs, each with a separate form, say form1 and form2. When I change tabs, the data in the form fields remains, as it should. When I submit form1, even if submitting to the same page, the page needs to reload and so the data in form2 is lost.

Is there any way to submit the data from form1 (and do the usual stuff with it, like putting in mysql, etc), but not touch the data in form2?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Ajax for form Submission, this will not refresh your page, which will save your data in another form.
 
Here is the official docs [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

 Quick Example [jQuery: AJAX Form Submission](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-AJAX-Form-Submission-P973.html)

Comment: Link of PHP everyday doesn't work